# How to make a 3x3 matrix with the pre-processed values in R?

Tags: r, matrix, 2d

I already have values of e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6 then how could i Put it into a 3x3 matrix in the following form in RStudio :

```
   [1] [2] [3]
[1] e1  e4  e5
[2] e4  e2  e6
[3] e5  e6  e3
```

Answer (score 4):

Fill in the off-diagonals, then fill in the diagonal:

```
x <- 1:6

out <- matrix(nrow=3,ncol=3)
out[c(which(lower.tri(out)), which(upper.tri(out)))] <- tail(x,3)
diag(out) <- head(x,3)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    4    5
#[2,]    4    2    6
#[3,]    5    6    3
```

Comment: Can this be generalized to a different dimension than 3? eg 4?

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting so many votes to be honest - @Onyambu 's answer below is a better generalisation.

Comment: Its because you answered the question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

```
vec2mat1=function(vec){
  l=length(vec)
  p=round(uniroot(function(x)x*(x+1)/2-l,c(0,1))[[1]],0)
  a=diag(vec[1:p],p)
  a[lower.tri(a)]=tail(vec,-p)
  a[upper.tri(a)]=t(a)[upper.tri(a)]
  a
}
vec2mat1(1:6)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    5
[2,]    4    2    6
[3,]    5    6    3

  vec2mat1(1:10)
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    6    7
[2,]    5    2    8    9
[3,]    6    8    3   10
[4,]    7    9   10    4
```

Comment: You could also calculate `p` via `(sqrt(8*l+1) - 1)/2` I believe. if I try to generalise my answer I pretty much end up with yours with the only difference being this calculation.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is column-wise

```
matrix(c(1, 4, 5, 
         4, 2, 6, 
         5, 6, 3), ncol=3)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    4    5
# [2,]    4    2    6
# [3,]    5    6    3
```